# can't use template mechanism of sonata / twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have to custom the sonata_admin_dashboard template on a symfony 4 application.

As figured in https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/templates.html, I've created a file config.yaml which contains :

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        layout:                         '@App/standard_layout_el.html.twig'
        dashboard:                      '@App/Default/dashboard_el.html.twig'
```

I've created the file @App/standard_layout_el.html.twig which begins by

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/standard_layout.html.twig' %}
```

and the file @App/Default/dashboard_el.html.twig which begins by

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/Core/dashboard.html.twig' %}
```

I've cleaned the cache.

But, when I run my application, in the symfony debug toolbar, i can see that the template used is @SonataAdmin/Core/dashboard.html.twig

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 0):

Config.yaml is wrong : i used config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml and the problem disappeared